# CSS in Wordpress: Customizer vs Child Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Where to put custom CSS in Wordpress: Customizer "Edit CSS" vs Child Theme style.css

My understanding is both options are ok and will be persistent if the parent theme changes. Customizer CSS is stored in the database, style.css is a file in the the directory.

What are other considerations of preferring one over the other when deciding where to put custom CSS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, those are the main differences.
If you need to backup your Customizer then a database backup would be required. While for the style.css file you would just backup the file.

When adding styles using Customizer it is often reflected in the `<head>` of the page and not in a stylesheet. It is generally bad practice. However that will depend on your theme.

Having said all of that I still add my CSS in Customizer as my theme permits it and it is just quicker since the other options for the theme are in the same panel.